# Can't stop windows system resource manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, resource-management

I'm using windows system resource manager to limit memory usage of a specific process. It works well but I've a problem when I stop management through console.

Let's say I'm using memory limit of 100MB on Powershell_ISE process. If I stop management, memory allocation can go up instantly, but if I start another Powershell_ISE process, it's still limited to 100MB even if the management is disabled.
Is this an expected behaviour? I noticed that windows system resource manager services is still running. Do I have to manually stop that one?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this issue reproducible on other systems? How does the system behave if you set the state to "Stopped" and restart the system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think you need to stop the process. However it's not very clear from the documentation:

"If Weighted_Remote_Sessions is set as the managing policy, running processes continue to be managed, even if the Windows System Resource Manager Management Status is set to STOPPED."

This would imply an apposite behavior of what you are describing.

I would definitely try to stop the service and observe the behavior

Both of the resources I am using don't mention the behavior you are describing:

[Use WSRM](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-windows-system-resource-manager-to-control-a-servers-powers/5054954)

[Windows System Resource Manangement on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754150.aspx)